# Simple Author, affiliation and email example fails in RevTex4-1

Tags: footnotes, titles, revtex, affiliation

I can't get the following simple author / email / affiliation code to function perfectly in a document for Journal of Mathematical Physics (JMP):

```
\documentclass[aip,jmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
...
\author{C. A. Brannen}
\email{xxx.yyy@wsu.edu}
\affiliation{Department of Physics, Washington State University,\\
Pullman, Washington   99164-2814}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

An annoying superscript (which is apparently referencing the affiliation which needs and possesses no number). I've reinstalled the latest updated MikTex 2.9 and TexnicCenter and get similar results on the template files, when I reduce them to just one author and one email.

I suspect that it's something about my installation. Anyone have a clue why this happens?

Comment: No, it is not your installation. I get the same (odd) result in my TeX Live2011 system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an unexpected result. However, you can get the proper result by using a `\noaffiliation` command between the `\author` and its `\affiliation`:

```
\documentclass[aip,jmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{C. A. Brannen}
\email{xxx.yyy@wsu.edu}
\noaffiliation
\affiliation{Department of Physics, Washington State University,\\
Pullman, Washington   99164-2814}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was having the same problem with my Mactex; I did not know what to do about it and then left it as it is. But now, I'll change it. Thanks Gonzalo

Comment: @victor: Instead of posting a “Thanks” as an additional answer, you should thank Gonzalo by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote though). I converted the non-answer to a comment.

Comment: Is there any way of putting the email under the name as opposed to next to references? ( I am submitting to another journal but using revtex)